# Doctrine2 migrations rename index for foreign keys

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, migration

I have problem with renaming indexes in doctrine:migrations:diff. Everytime when i ran this command, doctrine created sql queries to rename existing index in database. Is there any way to prevent this behaviour?

Full description:
we have big(about 2 hundres tables) old database on Oracle. There are naming conventions for constraint and indexes, for example:
we have table **RANDOM_KEY** and **USER**, foreign key (many to one) from RANDOM_KEY to USER, so coinstraint has name **FK_RANDOM_KEY_USER** and relevant index is **FK_RANDOM_KEY_USER_I**.

Entity declaration:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="RANDOM_KEY")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class RandomKey { 
 ...
```

Relations declaration:

```
/**
 * @var \User
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="USER_ID", referencedColumnName="USER_ID")
 * })
 */
private $user;
```

Result of migrations:diff commad is:

```
$this->addSql("ALTER INDEX FK_RANDOM_KEY_USER_I RENAME TO IDX_C54F7889A0666B6F");
```

I looked into depth of doctrine, tried some debugging. Between  indexes are no other differences, only name. Also I tried add **indexes** definition to **@ORM/Table**. Is there way to prevent index renaming?

Relevant composer data:

- "symfony/symfony": "2.4.*",
- "doctrine/orm": "2.5.*",
- "doctrine/dbal": "2.5.*",
- "doctrine/migrations": "1.0.*@dev",
- "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
- "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "2.1.*@dev",

Comment: This is driving me nuts. Did you ever figure out what was up, and where these weird IDX_BLAHBLAH hex value indexes came from?

Comment: I did not. This bugs is quite strange and I was unable to find the cause. After that we use some workaround (write migrations by ourselfs - but it is not solution for this problem).
Right now I am working for another company and I cant test posible solution.

Comment: Not sure if this helps you therefore as comment and not answer: Using symfony 4.3 and doctrine 2 we had similar problems. Adding indexes definition to @ORM/Table alone did not work but in combination with deleting the cache-folder it actually solved the problem.